# Why Can't I check my Terraria Version on Xbox360?

Tags: terraria-console

I've been having multiple troubles with Terraria including, not being able to find  the Queen Bee boss, the Lihzhard Temple and the Crimson. I think it's because of the Version of Terraria I have. The thing is, I have no idea what version of Terarria I have and I don't know how to check.

Comment: Do you have it on a disc, or downloaded from the Xbox store?

Comment: I have the Disk itself

Comment: If you have Xbox Live it should update for you.

Comment: I don't have Xbox Live

Answer (score 1):

If you have Xbox Live, whenever you connect it will update. If you don't, it will stay at the version you purchased the game.